# XSSFWorkbook memory issue

Tags: java, excel, memory, out

We have a requirement where we have to get a xlsx file from database and add 4 more sheets to it,.

I have written the below code to accomplish the same.

Code :

```
OPCPackage opcPackage=OPCPackage.open(tempExcelFile);
XSSFWorkbook xworkbook=new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);    
SXSSFWorkbook dbWorkBook = new SXSSFWorkbook(xworkbook, ApplicationConstants.FLUSH_LIMIT);
    // add sheets to dbworkBook
```

Now the size of the excel file in the database is about 10Mb and I am getting an OOM exception at

```
XSSFWorkbook xworkbook=new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

My memory settings are `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m` and I cannot change this number. I have seen some solutions where event API [has been asked to be used to solve the memory issue](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api)

My question is even if I use the event api to read the rows, how do I write it back into a `SXSSFWorkbook` object so that I can add 4 more sheets to it.

Comment: you should post a stacktrace of your out of mem. exception

Comment: Stack trace is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Your inherent problem here is that you are working with very large excel documents with a very small amount of memory.  I worked on parsing xlsx documents for a while and they can take a tremendous amount of memory to parse.  I would expect a 10 MB xlsx file to require somewhere in the ballpark of 1.5 - 2.5 GB worth of memory when unpacked in memory.

You're running up against a fundamental problem with the xlsx format (which, in case you don't know, is basically just a bunch of zipped XML documents).  Unless you have many gigs worth of memory to play around in, I really can't advise trying to open an xlsx file > 2 MB.